# Mac OS X (10.12.6) with Python 3.7.0a install lxml failed

Tags: macos, python-3.x, lxml

I've already **built libxslt(1.1.31) and libxml2(2.9.7) with homebrew and made link**:

```
brew install libxml2
Warning: libxml2 2.9.7 is already installed
brew install libxslt
Warning: libxslt 1.1.31 is already installed
```

**installed Xcode and tried to reinstall the command-line tools**:

```
xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

**exported C_INCLUDE_PATH**:

```
echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/

**tried this:**

```
STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
```

**tried easy_install and tried to build it from the source code.**

But, all methods failed. It really makes me confused.

The error message is :

```
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.31/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.7/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace


  src/lxml/etree.c:243289:21: error: no member named 'exc_state' in 'struct _ts'
      *type = tstate->exc_state.exc_type;
              ~~~~~~  ^
  src/lxml/etree.c:243290:22: error: no member named 'exc_state' in 'struct _ts'
      *value = tstate->exc_state.exc_value;
               ~~~~~~  ^
  [...(same error omitted)]
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1


  creating var
  creating var/folders
  creating var/folders/5m
  creating var/folders/5m/61f2z4pn75q0jbg65kn4cjzc0000gn
  creating var/folders/5m/61f2z4pn75q0jbg65kn4cjzc0000gn/T
  cc -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.31/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/5m/61f2z4pn75q0jbg65kn4cjzc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitmvd417vw.c -o var/folders/5m/61f2z4pn75q0jbg65kn4cjzc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitmvd417vw.o
  /var/folders/5m/61f2z4pn75q0jbg65kn4cjzc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitmvd417vw.c:2:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
  main (int argc, char **argv) {
  ^
  1 warning generated.
  cc var/folders/5m/61f2z4pn75q0jbg65kn4cjzc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitmvd417vw.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.31/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.6/lib -lxml2 -o a.out
  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.6/lib'
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
  Failed building wheel for lxml
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using:
`CFLAGS="-O0" sudo pip install lxml`

Hope this heps!